# How do I override SIddhi's default sequence and pattern matching functionality?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I'd like to write an extension to Siddhi that changes the way it finds event sequences and patterns, but I'm not sure which classes I should override/look into. Is anyone familiar enough with the source code to give me pointers? Is there an active dev mailing list?

Comment: dev@wso2.org is the dev mailing list of wso2.

Comment: Do you know how I can join it?

Comment: you can subscribe to mailing list using this page http://wso2.com/mail/.

Answer (score 1):

Mailing list is dev@wso2.org. You can subscribe by using WSO2 Mailing web page [1]

New SiddhiQL 3.0 has been released with WSO2 CEP 4.0.0. Please refer latest documentation on how to write Extensions [2]

In order to write a Siddhi extension your class needs to be extended from an Executor. There are few Executors on math, function and condition. Please refer whole list of executors [3].

Before writing an extension it is better to refer existing extensions and check how those have used executors [4]. Math PowerFunctionExtension is a simple extension which has been developed by extending function extension [5].

[1] http://wso2.com/mail/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Writing+Extensions+to+Siddhi

[3] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/executor

[4] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-extensions

[5] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-extensions/math/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/math/PowerFunctionExtension.java

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. But I think, since I want to change the pattern matching functionality, that I have to extend something other than Windows, Transformers, OutputAttributeProcessors or Functions. Do you know which classes are relevant?